# Android gradle bundleRelease cmd getting failed on mac

Tags: android, bash, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, java-17

I am using AGP version 8.1 & [Microsoft open JDK version 17.0.9](https://aka.ms/download-jdk/microsoft-jdk-17.0.9-macOS-x64.pkg)
gradle.wrapper.properties as below

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

On my app module build.gradle I have specified compleOptions as below

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

echo $JAVA_HOME return as

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

echo $PATH return as

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Application/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/opt/x11/bin
```

My default shell is bash, so I have configured java path on bash_profile as below

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-17.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

After saving above path on bash_profile I have executed below cmd source the changes

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

ERROR: When I tried to execute the "gradle bundleRelease" getting error as "Could not determine java version from 17.0.9"